# match full words only if index contains both full words and sub-words

Tags: elasticsearch

My index contains the following documents values:

```
"orange"
"orange juice"
"oran"
"ora"
"orang"
"orange "
"orange ju"
...
```

I want to query with `ora` and get only the documents with full words values: `orange` and `orange juice`.

Is there a way I can do this at query time? If not, can this be filtered somehow at index time?

Currently: I use a `prefix` query, but it matches all the documents.

Comment: It seems rather strange that your index contains such edge n-grams.  Did you read this documentation page ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html ) it seems to fit what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can chek the text while indexing and set some `boolean` field if it contains complete words, then use that field to filter.